# Storm cannot fetch message from Kafka with the message: Got fetch request with offset out of range

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I'm newbie in Storm world. In my topology, I am consuming data from Kafka and I use `SpoutConfig`.

With some tests, I got the following warning messages:

> 2015-10-01 23:31:51.753 s.k.KafkaUtils [WARN] Got fetch request with offset out of range: [85970]
>   2015-10-01 23:31:51.755 s.k.PartitionManager [WARN] Using new offset: 0

My `SpoutConfig` sets `ignoreZkOffsets` to `false` so I expect that when a new topology is submitted that it consumes from latest offset which is stored in Zookeeper.

However, when I kill my old topology and submit a new topology, the warning message shows up and the new topology can't consume from the offset. Could you give me a good idea if I forget something?

Comment: can you post the code you used to generate your SpoutConfig and your KafkaSpout?

Comment: @SQL.injection Thank you for your comments. Finally I found out what I've missed. I will answer my question below. Please refer to it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found out what I missed.
Since my topology consumes from two different Kafka sources, I made two `KafkaSpout` with different `SpoutConifg` instances each of which is allocated to each `KafkaSpout`.

But when I instantiate each `SpoutConfig` instance, I passed same id to each instance. It result in that there is only single znode with the id even if I expect to consume from two different sources.

Therefore, two `PartitionManager` tries to use the same single znode in which there is an offset info. If one of `PartitionManager` try to consume new tuple with the offset which is the one of the other side, the warning message shows.